# Blue screen of death while installing any Adobe Air application

Tags: installation, bsod, adobe-air

Whenever I try to install an Air application I get a Blue Screen and then my system restarts. I cannot even take a screenshot of it.

This happens with every air application I try to install.

I also searched for the same on **[Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/415553)** and found the same problem being faced by someone else.

His problem was resolved by uninstalling a software named "Folder Lock".

I searched my hard disk for this software and found one, so I deleted that software (shift+delete) and removed all it's traces from registry too but that still doesn't solved the problem.

I also tried disabling the antivirus software and then install the air application but this also didn't helped.

Here is the screenshot of the BSOD.
[image: Screen Shot Of BSOD]

I was able to install air applications earlier, but now I can't.

Anybody having same sort of problem. One colleague of mine is also having the same problem.

Please help me out.

**My system's config is as follows:** 

Windows XP Home sp3
Flash Builder 4, with SDK 4.1, 3.5 installed in it.
Adobe Air v 2.5
1.5 GB RAM
1.66 MHz processor

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disable in windows the "restart on error" function: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/ht/disautorestart.htm Afterwards you can read the BSOD and post the error message or try google. Otherwise it is hard to know exactly what is going on with your system.

EDIT:

It seems the uninstallation of Folder Lock was not completed. At least two other forums state, that the file windrvNT.sys is part of the Folder Lock. One suggestion would be the on from the following forum: http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f10/blue-screen-problem-159491.html

> Do you have Folder Lock installed on
>   your system? WinDrvNT.sys is a file
>   from FOLDER LOCK that may be causing
>   the system crashes.
>
> Uninstall folder lock and reboot.
>   Folder Lock creates a file called
>   windrvnt.sys, which can cause your
>   computer to crash repeatedly when it
>   conflicts with other software. Lets
>   see if your BSOD stops after
>   uninstalling Folder Lock. If you dont
>   want to uninstall, just rename it from
>   Windrvnt.sys to Windrvnt.old then
>   reboot. Its should be located in
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32

Have you used the the uninstall wizard of Folder Lock or do you have simply deleted Folder Lock manually? If you have done it manually you might want to reinstall it and then remove it with the wizard the next time.

To get a basic knowledge about bluescreens you might be interested in reading this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff542247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If you encounter a bluescreen often a search with the filename stated in the BSOD and/or the error code (In your case 0x000000E8) will help you. If possible search for what have been doing too. For example `Windows XP boot ERROR_CODE FILENAME` or in your case `Adobe ERROR_CODE FILENAME` this will generally give you a lot of links with people sharing your problem. If you are lucky you will find someone who has already solved it. But to know the exact filename and the error code you will have to read the BSOD, that is why one has to disable the reboot on error option (Which makes not too much sense on a workstation anyway imo).

Comment: Many users on adobe forums are facing this problem. There must have been some solution or it is something wrong with the air itself. Waiting for the answer....!!

Comment: @Darokthar: I have uploaded the screenshot of the BSOD, please have a look at it. I hope this will help you diagnose the problem. Thanks

Comment: @Gaurav Sharma edited my post.

Comment: @Darokthar: When I first read about "folder lock", I deleted the file straight away (Shift+Delete), then I posted over here and adobe forums. On adobe forums I was told to do a fresh installation and then uninstalltion of the "folder lock" software. I did all the mentioned steps but the problem persists.  Moreover the file "WinDrvNT.sys" seems to be a system file which when deleted may result in boot failure. Will it be safe to take a risk of renaming that file?

Comment: @Gaurav Sharma If the forums are right, it is safe. I guess windows will always state that files in System32 are system files and that it may make the system unstable. If you are not able to boot after renaming the file press F8 during booting and select the safe mode. There you should be able to rename the file again. If this does not help you will have to use the rescue console of a windows XP installation CD.

Comment: @Darokthar: Wow, that worked man. Thanks for your valuable suggestion. If superuser could allow I would have given you as much up votes as I wanted to :) Renaming that file solved the problem. Actually that file belonged to "folder locK" version 5.9 and I installed and then uninstalled version 6.0. That is why there was no effect. Thanks. :)